# Prism DI container: Dispose container when app is terminated

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

Does anyone know if I have to manually dispose the dependency injection container which is used in Prism.Forms when the app (Xamarin Android) is terminated?

**The problem:**

I register a singleton service in Prism.Forms' `RegisterServices` method. The singleton service itself subscribes to some classic .NET events (+=) and implements IDisposable which is used to unsubscribe (-=) the mentioned events. So far so good. Everything works fine.
When I start the Android part of the Xamarin.Forms app, then go back (Android back button) so that the app is closed again, launch the app again --> it results in multiple event subscriptions. Dispose is never run anywhere, thus, no event unsubscribes are done in the singleton service. This ultimately leads to memory leaks.

**Proposed solution** *(to be verified)*

I override `void OnDestroy` method in `MainActivity` and from there I call App.Container.Dispose() so that Prims' DI container is disposed when the Android app is terminated. This disposable of the DI container leads to Dispose being called on the earlier mentioned singleton service.

What do you think? I've never seen anyone doing this, but it solves an essential problem. How would you solve this problem?

Comment: If the app would be destroyed when you press the back button, the event subscriptions would die with it. Are you sure you subscribe to the events at the correct location, that is, when the app is created, and not when the activity is created or resumed or the app resumed...?

Comment: This is what I was assuming all these years... In this particular situation, I subscribe events in a singleton class. This class is registered at startup time in Prism's IoC container (DryIoc in my case). I would assume that - when the Android app is closed via back button, that the root process and all its memory is disposed. I can create a small sample app if it would help?

Comment: closing the app (back button, home button) doesn't mean it's immediately destroyed... it might survive for hours, if the device is idle, and if you tap its icon, it will be revived. Have a look at the android application lifecycle, it's almost as complicated as an activity's or a fragment's lifecycle... graphical illustration: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/f/f6/Android_application_life_cycle.png

Comment: @Haukinger, I would understand the lifecycle model differently: Either the app is backgrounded (home button) or destroyed (back button; or by manually closing the app). If the app is background, no new activity is created - everything is reused. When the app is closed and restarted, everything is recreated (including MainActivitiy, Xamarin Forms App, IoC container, etc...) but this is - obvisouly - not the case. Very frustrating.

Comment: there's no thing as "closing an app" in android (as the user), unfortunately, only background and then random termination by the os... I agree that this is really annoying and overly complicated, especially if you want the app to do work while in the background. Good luck trying to make sure that it won't get terminated at one point in time or another...